# How to create jquery layout dynamically?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-droppable, jquery-layout

I am using jquery layout plugin and creating a nested layout when I drag an image and drop on a section of jquery layout, works fine for first time but second time it's not working.

I am using following code on drop function of image -
    $("#mainContent").empty();
    $("#mainContent").layout(DashboardGenerator.layoutSettings_Inner);

Comment: please provide more code

Comment: Let me put this in another way, I have a container div ("#mainContent"), I am inserting some more divs inside it and then calling the layout method, works for me for first time but when I am again doing the same process it's not working, is it because I have already bind layout() method with #mainContent?

Comment: Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask Show some javascript. Show some HTML. Give us context. Give us the functions your using. Without these things you will not find answers are forthcoming.